# Flutter how to set widget full screen size on orientation landscape?

Tags: flutter, dart

I had an issue in full screen view on orientation landscape mode, the problem is only with some devices nokia, redmi and one plus in landscape mode in left side of screen not covered fully.attaching screen shot below

[image]

in left side that space was my mobile walpaper, widget not covering full screen. so how do i solve this ?

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  bool isFullScreen = false;

  /* To Update Screen Resolution Normal */
  void updateResolutionNormal() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
  }

  /* To Update Screen Resolution LandscapeLeft,LandscapeRight */
  void updateResolutionLandscape() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;
                if (isFullScreen) {
                  updateResolutionLandscape();
                } else {
                  updateResolutionNormal();
                }
              });
            },
            child: Center(child: Text("Hai"))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just ran your code on my machine and built it into my Redmi Note 8, and it works fine. The entire screen is filled up when I clicked to switch to landscape mode. So I can't tell what the problem is.

Comment: @Chichebe thanks. i tested with Nokia 6.1plus and Redmi Note 7S not filled up entire screen .. and after that i tested  with samsung j7 pro it was working.. so what will be the problem in nokia 6.1 and redmi note 7s am not getting.

Comment: @JaiTechie Wrap the Scaffold with a SafeArea widget. Kindly, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that could work, try:

```
body: Container(
        /// Try adding a width and height to your container like so. I set the width and height to the full dimensions of the device
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;
                if (isFullScreen) {
                  updateResolutionLandscape();
                } else {
                  updateResolutionNormal();
                }
              });
            },
            child: Center(child: Text("Hai"))),
      ),
```

Hope it works!

Comment: No luck, still same tried with above mediaQuery not filled screen. and also tried with 

`_mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);

screenWidthpx = _mediaQueryData.size.width * _mediaQueryData.devicePixelRatio;
screenHeightpx = _mediaQueryData.size.height * _mediaQueryData.devicePixelRatio;

screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;`